# Error message in EXM when using the external image hosting link

Tags: sitecore-client, media-library, exm, links, html

I have created an `Email campaign` via Sitecore, and in my HTML code for the E-mail I used an external link for the image (from the media hosting). When I wanted to send it out via list delivery, I got an error with below message

```
your email message contains an image that is not available on the server.
```

But it is specific for me to use external hostings for the email images. Is it at all possible via `Sitecore EXM manager` or I can only send campaigns using the `Sitecore Media Library`?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you on? Do you have an `Embed Images` setting set to `true` for your Manager Root? In theory, if you have an absolute link to that external image all should work correctly and the modifyHyperlink pipeline shouldn't modify it. What is your target image URL, can you access it yourself?

Comment: Hi @KateOrlova Thank you for your answer! I have 8.2 sitecore version. Tried your suggestion with the Embed Images. The email was sent but the images became attachments, not displayed in the mail iteself. Target image URL is absolute and opens just fine. The problem is with the EXM sending :(

Comment: Right, likely you are on EXM v3.5, but it is still old... I can only think about a link encoding issue that can be resolved by installing this patch https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002429 Will be worth checking it